# Error in my SQL statement using SELECT FROM INNERJOIN WHERE

Tags: php, sql

```
$query = "
SELECT * FROM product_new
INNER JOIN user_details ON user_details.user_id = product_new.product_enter_by 
INNER JOIN category ON category.category_id = product_new.category_id 
INNER JOIN brand ON brand.brand_id = product_new.brand_id 
WHERE product_new.branch_id = $_SESSION['branch_id']
";
```

I use this query to display a list of products that join with a product brand, product category and user details which is filter by branch_id. The list for all products is displaying but when I add the where clause it turns out to be an error. Can I know how to fix it?

**Error:**

> DataTables warning: table id=product_data - Ajax error. For more
>   information about this error, please see datatables.net/tn/7

The table didn't show any list

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: which type of error you get?

Comment: **DataTables warning: table id=product_data - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7**  The table  didn't show any list

Comment: error not in query, error in ajax datatable so search about this

Comment: But without that WHERE clause the datatable perfectly fine and show all product. Is it still error in ajax?

Comment: @Hana Kindly print the query and give us the exact query. I want to know what's the value in session variable!

Comment: @Hana, May be you should use the left join instead of inner join.

Comment: @smita **No data available in table** appeared in the datatable. It just the same as inner join. Without WHERE clause, it show all the records.

Comment: @ABHI I'm sorry I can't print the query, I don't know why it didn't show any output

Answer (score 0):

I guess you gotta quote the $_SESSION value. Please try  this:

```
$query = "
SELECT * FROM product_new
INNER JOIN user_details ON user_details.user_id = product_new.product_enter_by 
INNER JOIN category ON category.category_id = product_new.category_id 
INNER JOIN brand ON brand.brand_id = product_new.brand_id 
WHERE product_new.branch_id = " . $_SESSION['branch_id'];
```

Comment: **No data available in table** appeared in the data table

Comment: So  the query is now correctly formed, but there is no data available with the branch_id. You should be good to go now.

Comment: But actually there's some data in the branch_id

Comment: And there is some data in the table related with the branch_id as well? Do you receive any returns when you execute the query "SELECT * FROM product_new WHERE branch_id = " . $_SESSION['branch_id'];

Comment: still no data avaiable  but without WHERE it can display the whole data

Comment: So if there is still no data with this select query, either the value inside the session branch_id is not correct, or something else with your table is not correct.

Comment: May be you should use the left join instead of inner join.